# Step by step C compilation using GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I am trying to make the four steps that takes to transform from C source into an executable with GCC. The first 3 steps works as expected, but the last one gives me problems. I have two files: `writeByte.h` and `writeByte.c`, which contains the following:

```
// writeByte.h
// USED GCC COMMANDS BY ORDER:
// 1 - "gcc writeByte.c -o pre-processed.i -E"
// 2 - "gcc pre-processed.i -o assembled.s -S"
// 3 - "gcc assembled.s -o compiled.o -c"
// 4 - ???

void writeByte(char* addr, char val);
```

and

```
// writeByte.c
#include "writeByte.h"
void writeByte(char* addr, char val) { *addr = val; }
```

Supposedly, to link a file, I have to execute `gcc compiled.o -o executable`, but it says that at `.text+0x20`, reference to `main` is undefined, so I don't know how to follow.

Comment: In C, execution starts with `main`. Your program must have a main function which then can call writeByte.

Comment: @Jens Oh... I don't know how I forgot about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Define a `main()` function, and your program will work.**

From the C specification [C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:201x / N1548)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)

> #### 5.1.2 Execution environments
>
> Two execution environments are defined: *freestanding* and *hosted*.
>   […]
>
> #### 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment
>
> In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined.
>   […]
>
> #### 5.1.2.2 Hosted environment
>
> […]
>
> #### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> The function called at program startup is named `main`. […]

Furthermore:

> #### J2 Undefined behavior
>
> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> - […]
> - A program in a hosted environment does not define a function named `main` using one of the specified forms (5.1.2.2.1).

## Hosted Environment

**This is most likely your case.**
This applies to typical operating systems, such as Linux, Unix, Mac OS X, Windows, Amiga OS, and many more. In that case, your environment typically is the hosted environment.

Given you run your C compiler and linker without any options that would select or influence the environment, and given the target is such a typical operating system, and you finally link, the assumption made by the C compiler and linker will be a hosted environment. As described above, this means that you need to provide a `main()` function so that the hosted environment knows where to start your C program. Because you did not provide a `main` function, clause **J2 Undefined behavior** applied, and the linker refused to complete its job.

Note: Under the hood, these operating systems actually provide their own custom interface, see below.

**Solution: Provide a `main()` function.**

## Freestanding Environment

Freestanding environments typically occur when developing firmware or operating system yourself. In that case, the entry point is defined by the CPU. Most CPUs will either start execution at a pre-defined address, or at a configurable address read from a vector table specified at a pre-defined address.

## Custom Environments

Besides that, there are custom environments. The two most common custom environments are:

### The typical OS

In order to be able to do more than specified by the C specification, operating systems define their own environment. This environment is typically an extension of the hosted environment, and will use the entry point specified by the linker. Typically, that entry point is actually another function, often called `_start`, which is provided by a default library such as libglibc. This function `_start` is called by the OS, and that function `_start` then actually calls `main`.

So, instead of providing `main`, it would be possible to provide `_start`, or an equivalent, instead.
You could write your own `_start` function or entry point.
However, that risks that your program would unnecessarily be less portable, and that you have to deal with operating system issues that a hosted environment is hiding from you.
It is therefore not recommended for "normal" programs by "normal" developers.

### DLL environments

When programs are supposed to run as plugins for other programs, those other programs define a custom environment.
Typically, that custom environment is realized as DLL (Dynamic Link Library).

### Embedded environments

For several embedded systems, the toolchains (compiler etc.) come with libraries which provide a custom environment for that system. These environments have features which ranks somewhere between a freestanding environment and a hosted environment, and the entry points depend on the corresponding toolchain. To avoid confusion that stems from unexpected entry point names, toolchains usually use `main`, `start`, `_start`, `Start` or `_Start` as names for the entry point.

Comment: Executables don't start from `main`. Usually they start from `_start` symbol, which eventually calls `main`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian That's right, however, that's OS specific and not defined in C. I've updated the answer to clarify that, thanks for the input.